# How to handle this Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/api'

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, rest

I understand what the error message says - Spring cannot determine based on the path which method it should use, but I lack the idea or the experience to handle this elegantly.

Basically, I have 2 Controllers with the same endpoint `/api/notification`: (I've omitted some details not relevant here)

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @PostMapping(
        value = "/api/notification",
        consumes= {
        "application/message+xml",
        "text/xml",
        "application/xml"},
        produces = "application/json"
    )
    public ResponseEntity<String> message(@RequestBody Message message) {
        log.info("Handling message for id {}", message.getId());
        handleMessage(message);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("{\"result\":\"Message received\"}");
    }
}
```

And second one:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class EventController {

    @PostMapping(
        value = “/api/notification",
        consumes= {
        "application/event+xml",
        "text/xml",
        "application/xml"},
        produces = "application/json"
    )
    public ResponseEntity<String> event(@RequestBody Event event) {
        log.info("Handling event for id {}", event.getId());
        handleEvent(event);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("{\"result\”:\”Event received\"}");
    }
}
```

So they are pretty much identical, except that they consume 2 different xml schemas (`message` and `event`) and also they handle and parse these xml objects differently (again omitted here for simplicity).

So my question will be, what is the best way to tackle this and possibly combine these two while still preserving the same endpoint? I cannot unfortunately change the endpoint, cause that will be a breaking change.

I tried to combine them in one controller, with `@RequestBody Object` and using `instanceof`, but that did not work and it also does not seem like a particularly good idea.

Comment: Something simpler you could try is just to remove the ambiguity by removing "text/html" and "application/xml" from the `consumes` set. I don't know whether that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, where you check the content-type header and decide what to try to parse from the XML string. You would need to use your XML parser to implement the `parseMessage` function, and a similar `parseEvent` function.

```
       @PostMapping(
                value = "/api/notification",
                consumes= {
                        "application/message+xml",
                        "application/event+xml",
                        "text/xml",
                        "application/xml"},
                produces = "application/json"
        )
        public ResponseEntity<String> message(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) {
            final String contentType = httpEntity.getHeaders().get("Content-Type").get(0);
            if (contentType.equals("application/message+xml")) {
                Message m = parseMessage(httpEntity.getBody());
                log.info("Handling message for id {}", message.getId());
                handleMessage(message);
                return ResponseEntity.ok("{\"result\":\"Message received\"}");
            } else if (contentType.equals("application/event+xml")) {
                ... event processing ...
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's an intuitive thing to do, but the problem is this endpoint is being called from an external client outside of my reach and I checked how are they calling me.... they are just using "text/xml" as content and not the concrete schema :(

Comment: I ended up specifying a new endpoint, which they would need to talk to (as they were reluctant to use the right content-types (wtf really). But thanks for the answer!